# Placing snippet in div

Tags: javascript

Hope you can help?

I'm trying to place the contents of a snippet within a div (named "program") with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
document.getElementById("program").innerHTML = '{% include 'snippets/program-amsterdam-3day-bgn-eng.rain' %}';
// ]]></script>
```

but is't not working. Can anyone see what's wrong with my code?

This does work independently:

```
{% include 'snippets/program-amsterdam-3day-bgn-eng.rain' %}
```

Comment: could be  "{% include 'snippets/program-amsterdam-3day-bgn-eng.rain' %}"

Answer (score 2):

You're escaping your string with unbalance quotes:

```
document.getElementById("program").innerHTML = '{% include 'snippets/program-amsterdam-3day-bgn-eng.rain' %}';
```

Try using double quotes to surround your include statement:

```
document.getElementById("program").innerHTML = "{% include 'snippets/program-amsterdam-3day-bgn-eng.rain' %}";
```

And make sure to escape any quotes within the included file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately still not working.

Comment: I want to say this, but it's just an idea. Probably you're using some kind of template engine, and injecting the code like that could not work, because the template has been already rendered. If you would provide a more accurate example, I am sure I can help.

Comment: @Eddy If possible, please provide what the rendered content looks look when you view the source of the rendered page.

Comment: It now shows {% include 'snippets/program-amsterdam-3day-bgn-eng.rain' %} as tekst on the page. Check under the "program" button please.

Comment: What templating engine are you using?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question. I am working in a back office of a webshop provider

Comment: What program or language is causing `{% include ... %}` to include the contents of another file?

Comment: The engine is Rain. The language is Rain

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot provide further assistance as I do not know what Rain is. If you're referring to [RainTPL](http://rainphp.github.io/raintpl/Documentation.html), their documentation seems to indicate that it shouldn't have '%' symbols. I don't know, sorry I can't help further. Thought it was just an issue with your quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot regardless! Maybe you could have a look here? http://developers.seoshop.com/themes/getting-started/rain  Towards the bottom of the page it mentions the include function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes as your string delimiters since you are using single-quotes inside your string:

```
document.getElementById("program").innerHTML = "{% include 'snippets/program-amsterdam-3day-bgn-eng.rain' %}";
```

Alternatively, you could also escape the single-quotes:

```
document.getElementById("program").innerHTML = '{% include \'snippets/program-amsterdam-3day-bgn-eng.rain\' %}';
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave, Tried it both but it's not working. When I just use {% include 'snippets/program-amsterdam-3day-bgn-eng.rain' %} somewhere else and on its own, it is loading the file to include. So the problem seems not to be in this part of the code. And yes, I've double-checked the program div.